# How is Firebase analytics custom metrics calculated

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

I'm tracking data associated with an event, for this I put a parameter of programProgress(0 - 1), I created this in the Firebase console as a custom metric.
When I check the console all I see is a graph(attached) of what seems to be the average, no segmentation(like custom dimensions), no explanations. I've gone through multiple documentations and haven't found an answer.

Questions:

- Is this graph an average of all data collected, what's the formula?
- Is there a way to segment it(preferably in the console) and see amounts for different values i.e. 20 hits for 0.3, 40 for 0.4 etc
- Is there a way to segment and see values for different custom dimensions i.e. 30 hits of 0.9 for x dimension(preferably in the console)

Thanks

[image: programProgress graph]

Comment: GA4 is still a raw product. We're seeing severe issues with custom dimensions and general UI bugs. Custom metrics are much more rarely used than CDs, so, organically, much less attention is paid to them. We normally suggest either not using GA4 for real analysis or downloading its data elsewhere and doing real analysis using adequate tools. This is not an answer, however. I'd like to know the answer to this one too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way to achieve what you're looking for would be to go into the Google Analytics (GA4) console directly and using the [Segment Comparison](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en&ref_topic=3123779#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) feature in either the [User Explorer](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6339208?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) or [Cohort Explorer](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9670133?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) techniques.

You can build segments using the `programProgress` parameter and create multiple for each range you want to specify.